# Can view IIS8 web site at localhost, but not at 127.0.0.1

Tags: networking, localhost

My ultimate goal is to be able to view my local IIS web site from a different device on my LAN. I started by attempting to access the host's IP address, but that failed, so I did some reading and attempted to fix the problem, but was unable to. In my travels, I noticed that I was able to view my app at

```
http://localhost/<app-name>
```

but navigating to

```
http://127.0.0.1/<app-name>
```

or

```
http://<computer-name>/<app-name>
```

results in either a 503 error or "unable to display this page" error.

My app pool appears to be configured correctly and I've fiddled around with dozens of different bindings and ports but the results are all the same.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: if you type 'nslookup localhost' in a command prompt, what do you get? also what are the contents of c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts ? Win7 and forward try to use dns to resolve the name localhost, but some services don't like that. if you add '127.0.0.1 localhost' to the hosts file, and save, does you address resolve correctly?

Comment: The result of nslookup localhost is "Name: localhost  Addresses: ::1          127.0.0.1". Adding 127.0.0.1 localhost to my hosts file doesn't change anything. Hosts file is otherwise empty. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was related to an https redirect on app startup that I'd missed.